# Variable not being replaced (learning Dynamic PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The below code returns error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, I think may be because PL/SQL runtime engine(or something I don't know what) is trying to treat `table_in` as a Table but why would it do so, I have already `table_in` declared as variable.

The `ex26011601` table exists with values in the same schema.

```
set serveroutput on

declare
    function tabcount (table_in in varchar2)
        return pls_integer
    is
        l_return pls_integer;
    begin
        select count(*) into l_return from table_in;
        return l_return;
    end;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(tabcount('ex26011601'));
end;
```

I understand `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` would solve the purpose. What I am trying to get is why is it necessary and whats wrong with current statement that 'table_in' could not be treated as variable even after being declared in the scope. Or what is the reason why a variable is not expected there?

Comment: It's because of your select statement

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't just indiscriminately substitute any arbitrary text that happens to match the parameter name. In the context of parameterised cursors, it only evaluates bind variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand EXECUTE IMMEDIATE would solve the purpose. What I am
>   trying to get is why is it necessary and whats wrong with current
>   statement that 'table_in' could not be treated as variable even after
>   being declared in the scope.

As per oracle documentation : [Static SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102)

*A PL/SQL static SQL statement can have a PL/SQL identifier wherever its SQL counterpart can have a placeholder for a bind variable. The PL/SQL identifier must identify either a variable or a formal parameter.To use PL/SQL identifiers for table names, column names, and so on, use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement*

> In PL/SQL, you need dynamic SQL to run when :
>
> - SQL whose text is unknown at compile time
>
>   For example, a SELECT statement that includes an identifier that is unknown at compile time (such as a table name) or a WHERE clause in
>     which the number of sub clauses is unknown at compile time.
> - SQL that is not supported as static SQL

[Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102)

Comment: _SQL whose text is unknown at compile time ._ helped

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as you said oracle pl/sql syntax does not allowing that, pass table name by variable. As you also said you can do it only by dynamic sql and execute immediate:

```
execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || table_in
into l_return;
```

Comment: `table_in` is a variable which stores name of the table. I am tryong to count total number of rows in table.